# Method overloading - good or bad design?

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

I like to overload methods to support more and more default cases. What is the performance impact of method overloading? From your experience, is it advisable to overload methods? What is the limit? What are the workarounds?

Comment: You may find this blog post of mine useful: [The Hidden Dangers of Method Overloading](https://www.yegor256.com/2023/08/01/method-overloading.html). I argue that method overloading may negatively impact code quality, because maintaining two or more implementations under the same name gives rise to concealed semantics, which inevitably result in misunderstandings and functional defects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overloading has no impact on performance; it's resolved by the compiler at compile-time.

As for design guidance, see the design guidelines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you're using C# 4.0 you can save your fingers some work and use [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

1. Performance impact,
   as far as I know, it's like defining a new method. The performance impact is space on your harddrive.
2. Advisable to overload methods,
   Definitely, it's provides convenience
3. What is the limit,
   As much Harddrive space as you have.

Comment: Don't forget the memory use, because the methods will be JITted ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Away from performance, overloading if used intensively will for sure lead to confusion once somebody starts to maintain the code, I prefer doing this:

```
Person GetPersonByID( int id );
Person GetPersonByName( String name );
```

on this:

```
Person GetPerson( int id );
Person GetPerson( String name );
```